# New Jersey governor data on Dave's Redistricting?

Tags: united-states, election, redistricting, new-jersey

There is a tool called [Dave's Redistricting](https://davesredistricting.org) which allows people to simulate drawing congressional districts far more easily than older software can.

They have added the Virginia governor election which Youngkin narrowly won. But they did not add the New Jersey race, which was a fairly close Democratic win, and far less than one would expect a Democrat to win by statewide in New Jersey under normal circumstances (the state has been won by Democrats on the presidential level by around 15 percentage points every election since 2008).

I believe precinct data is lying around somewhere because it is typically needed to compute results by congressional district since the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2021_New_Jersey_gubernatorial_election#Results_by_congressional_district) has the results listed. I want to know if it's possible to import that data into Dave's Redistricting because I want it for a project I'm doing.

Comment: I suspect that the answer is no but that the right place to ask is feedback@davesredistricting.org.

Comment: You should not that NJ had a **Republican** governor for an 8 year period since 2008, despite as you mentioned voting Democrat for the presidential election by a significant margin. I *would* expect a closer race, due to that information, than you may expect simply looking at the presidential election.